# Brew install failing on OS X - possibly something to do with new XCode

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, homebrew, fontconfig

I'm trying to do a brew install of fontconfig on OS X 10.8.3 and I'm being thrown with a nasty error. I have XCode 4.6.1 installed.

```
$ brew install fontconfig
 ==> Installing fontconfig dependency: pkg-config
 ==> Downloading https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bottles/pkg-config-0.28.mountain_lion.bottle.tar.gz
 ######################################################################## 100.0%
 ==> Pouring pkg-config-0.28.mountain_lion.bottle.tar.gz   /usr/local/Cellar/pkg-config/0.28: 10 files, 636K
 ==> Installing fontconfig
 ==> Downloading http://fontconfig.org/release/fontconfig-2.10.91.tar.gz Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/fontconfig-2.10.91.tar.gz 
 ==> Patching patching file src/fcarch.h
 ==> ./configure --with-add-fonts=/Library/Fonts,~/Library/Fonts --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/fontconfig/2.10.91
 ==> make install 
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) 
 make[2]: *** [libfontconfig.la]  Error 1 
 make[1]: *** [install] Error 2 
 make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1

 READ THIS: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting
```

There seems to be very little information around this issue and it's pretty painful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***SOLVED***

Turned out I had the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH env variable set to use with Oracle, and this was causing reference to 32-bit libraries.

**Unsetting the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH env variable fixed this.**

Anybody using an Oracle client on their mac should be wary of this!